# Code does not work in class implementation but works fine in functions.php file

Tags: wp-cron, cron, oop

I am trying to clean up my codes and separate them in class files.

I have this block of code that works perfectly fine where it sets the status of events older than a week to trash when I add it in the **functions.php** file:

```
if ( ! wp_next_scheduled( 'trash_week_old_events' ) ) {
    wp_schedule_event( time(), 'daily' );
}

add_action( 'trash_week_old_events', 'trash_events' );

function trash_events() {
   $args = array(
       'post_type' => 'event',
       'post_status' => 'publish',
       'date_query' => array(
           array(
               'before' => '1 week ago'
           )
       )
   ); 

   $query = new WP_Query( $args );
   $posts = $query->get_posts();

   foreach( $posts as $post ) { 
       $updated_post_info = array(
           'ID'           => $post->ID,
           'post_status'  => 'trash'
       );

       wp_update_post( $updated_post_info );
   }

 }
```

But when I try to convert this to a class, when I try to run the CRON job in the admin area, it doesn't work.

```
class EventsWPCron {

    public function __construct() {

        if ( ! wp_next_scheduled( 'trash_week_old_events' ) ) {
            wp_schedule_event( time(), 'daily' );
        }

        add_action( 'trash_week_old_events', array( $this, 'update_events' ) ); 

    }

    private function update_events() {
        $args = array(
            'post_type' => 'event',
            'post_status' => 'publish',
            'date_query' => array(
                array(
                    'before' => '1 week ago'
                )
            )
        ); 

        $query = new WP_Query( $args );
        $posts = $query->get_posts();

        foreach( $posts as $post ) { 
            $updated_post_info = array(
                'ID'           => $post->ID,
                'post_status'  => 'trash'
            );

            wp_update_post( $updated_post_info );
        }


    }     


}

new EventsWPCron();
```

Is there something that I am missing in the class implementation why it is not working? I tried searching around but I am not able to find any clear reference.

Comment: `update_events()` needs to be a public method.

Comment: @NathanJohnson you should post answers as answers, no rep earned from upvoting comments!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Nathan has said in his comment above, the `update_events()` function needs to be a public function, not a private function:

- `public` scope to make that variable/function available from anywhere, other classes and instances of the object.
- `private` scope when you want your variable/function to be visible in its own class only.
- `protected` scope when you want to make your variable/function visible in all classes that extend current class including the parent class.

Comment: I would add that PHP should be throwing warnings about this in your error log too